# How to adjust speaker volume independent of headphones

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I have a set of speakers as well as my headphones running through the same dac and I was wondering if it's possible to adjust the volume of the speaker without effecting my headphones.

Answer (score 0):

If they're running through the same DAC, then there's no way to do such an adjustment anywhere but "downstream" of the DAC. For example, if your DAC has separate volume controls for its speaker outputs vs its headphone output.

You have tagged Windows and Windows 10 with your question, which tells me you're looking for a way to do this within Windows. But since Windows sees the DAC as a single device, there's no way for Windows to do that. Windows sends just one stream of digital data to the DAC, not one for speakers and one for headphones.

Comment: yeah I thought that might be the answer. I figured it was worth a try though, thanks for your help :)

Comment: There is an easy workaround: Buy an inexpensive USB sound device and use that for either 'phones or speakers.